# genexus: File with extract always and generator any not copied Gx X Ev 3 U5

Tags: file, genexus

I created a javascript file and added to the Genexus Files with `Extract Always` and Generator `Any`, but it's not copied to the output folder (I changed it to generator `CSharp` and with different Extract to Path, but I cannot make it to work)

There is some mistake, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Ariel, what you're doing is correct. 
Check the output Window, it should be telling you where is it being copied. Also, double check the properties in case some of them did not stay as you expect.

But there's nothing wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: I've checked again. If I make a Rebuild All in the output window doesn't appear my js file

Comment: maybe it's time to file a bug to support